# error: var is not defined while it is defined

Tags: javascript

1. I want to know, why it says that the third "S is not defined", because S is defind

```
function startTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  var S = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  m = checkTime(m);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = S + ":" + m;
  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

**this S here**

```
var a = S + m
    
if (a === 2215) {console.log("lol"); };
```

Comment: You create S variable locally inside function startTime(). To use it outside, you should create it globally

Comment: thanks didnt think that could be a problem

Comment: Some scope discussion here: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)  and here [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) and then there's [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

```
var S,m;
function startTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  S = today.getHours();
  m = today.getMinutes();
  m = checkTime(m);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = S + ":" + m;
  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

var a = S + m
    
if (a === 2215) {console.log("lol"); };
```

You forgot to shift **"S"** to global scope, var has a function scope, if variable is declared with **var**, can access only it's function scope

Comment: This still wont works because now `m` is not defined ;)

Comment: Please shift m to top like s variable